# Копирование Базы данных

Tags: база-данных, sql-server

Есть база, допустим с именем "база1", как создать базу, допустим с именем "база2", с точной копией "базы1" ?
База на MS SQL Server 2008

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть куча вариантов:

1. копирование базы (ЕМНИП, в
       экспорте-импорте),
2. <strike>копирование файлов базы,
       присоединение под новым
           именем</strike> (это самый плохой вариант),
3. Восстановление из бэкапа, в качестве источника выбираете существующую базу,
4. делаете бэкап существующей (или берете имеющийся) и восстанавливаете из него.

Comment: Есть еще один вариант(просто до кучи). Если бд не очень большая то можно сгенерировать скрипты и потом накатить на нужный сервер.

Answer (score 0):

Так же есть вариант - использование утилиты [SqlPackage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh550080(v=vs.103).aspx),
с помощью которой мы делаем снимок схемы данных. 
После создаем пустую базу с именем "база2".
Затем через VisualStudio, используя ssdt, сравниваем схемы пустой базы и dacpack'a -  у нас появляется возможность ставить только то, что необходимо в данной базе.