# Копирование базы данных из одного инстанса в другой

Tags: sql-server

Народ, подскажите как без создания промежуточного bak файла сдернуть базу с одного инстанса в другой, если я имею подключение к обоим в mssms? Они даже физически расположены на одном компе. Просто базы большие, поэтому я не хочу выполнять промежуточный шаг по созданию бэкапа, с целью накатить его на другой инстанс.

Еще нюанс. Вот тут [Копирование Базы данных](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/201179/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%91%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%8B-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85) я нашел возможные варианты, но

3. Восстановление из бэкапа, в качестве источника выбираете существующую базу

тоже не для моего случая. Так как базы в разных истансах, я не могу выбрать в качестве источника восстановления существующую базу.

**UPD:**

Целевая база лежит на сервере версии 2014, сервер назначения версии 2005.

Comment: Linked Server. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188279(v=sql.105).aspx Rowset Functions. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187957(v=sql.105).aspx